# Matching Cell's Value to Row then directing to value in a column of the Row

Tags: excel, vba

I need code to match a cell to a row number on a separate sheet, then to find the value on that row to a separate column.

For example (This isn't code but rather what I need verbatim):

```
For Each cell In rng 'Separate worksheet
Match value on worksheet("IO Table").Range("A:A") then find row
Match row.column("J") value = "DI" Then
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need this in a worbook function take a look at `INDEX` and `MATCH`. The first returns the what is at the specified row and column in the specified range and the latter returns the row or column in the specified range matching the value to search for. (The search option 0 is required to search for exact matches.)

If you want to do the same in VBA, you can use the `Find` method of the range object. It returns the cell where the match is found and `Nothing` if there is no match. On this range you can use `EntireRow` and then select whatever column you want via the `Cells` property.

Comment: I'm actually using Index and Match within the document, already. I'm creating a generator and I'm using the VBA to create the worksheets from templates based off of two factors: type (DI, DO, AI, AO) and count (32, 16, 8, etc.)

Comment: Does the `Find` method then do what you need or do you just need the `Formula` property to insert the formulas programmatically?